# C++ Friend Functions in separate header and .cpp files

Tags: c++, function, class, friend

```
//A.h
class A{
friend bool compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(Entry arg1, Entry arg2);
}

//A.cpp
#include "A.h"
bool A::compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(Entry arg1, Entry arg2)
{
    bool b = arg1.sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(numbers) < arg2.sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(numbers);
    return b;
}
```

I get the error compareEntry_sum_Pct_nonMega is not a member of A.

Comment: Is compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega inside of a class declaration? If not, then it's not part of class A

Comment: May help you http://geeksquiz.com/friend-class-function-cpp/

Comment: @cm161 that shows how to create a friend function inside one file, I want to declare the friend function in my header file and define it in my .cpp file, which includes my header.

Comment: A friend function is a friend, not a member, so you don't define it with the `A::` qualifier that means a member.

Comment: You need to ask better questions with complete code examples. This question shows an incomplete snippet of code, e.g. you have not shown the `numbers` member of `A`, and so the question should be closed as off-topic, or you should edit it to improve it.

Comment: @Jonathan The complete code is 10 source files, it would be too long and tedious to go through all of them to answer a simple question.

Comment: @TommySaechao, poor excuse, you need to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/ and learn to ask better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//A.h
class A{
friend bool compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(A& obj, Entry arg1, Entry arg2); <-- CHANGE done here
}

//A.cpp
#include "A.h"
bool compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(A& obj, Entry arg1, Entry arg2) <-- CHANGE done here
{
    // Using 'obj', all members (private as well) of class A can be accessed <-- CHANGE done here
    bool b = arg1.sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(numbers) < arg2.sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(numbers);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

```
bool A::compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(Entry arg1, Entry arg2)
```

A friend function of a class is not its member function.
So, `A::` is telling the compiler that it should treat this function as a member function but it's clearly not a member function.

so, take out `A::` ie scope resolution.

A function cannot be both member function of a class `T` and friend function of `T`. If it is already a member function, then, what's the point in making it friend of that class.

If you were intending to use one class function as a friend of another class, then you can use it as below:

```
class B
{
public:
    void fB(A& a); 
    void fB2(A& a); 
};

class A
{
public:
    friend void B::fB(A& a);
    void fA(){}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined "friend bool compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(Entry arg1, Entry arg2);" as a friend function, you are telling the compiler that the function compareEnty_sumPct_nonMega is a non-member function which should have access to private methods and variables of the class "A". But when you define the function in A.cpp, you are defining it as a member function of class "A" since your definition has "bool **A::**compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(Entry arg1, Entry arg2)". Remove the A:: in A.cpp and try compiling.

Change your A.cpp to -

```
//A.cpp
#include "A.h"
bool compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(Entry arg1, Entry arg2)
{
    bool b = arg1.sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(numbers) < arg2.sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(numbers);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: When I take out the **A::** I no longer have access to **numbers** member because **numbers** is a member of type class **A**

My goal here is to declare the friend function in the .h file and then define it in the .cpp file.

Comment: @TommySaechao, to access the `numbers` member variable it needs to be a member function ... so why are you defining it as a friend? A friend is not a member. If you want a member function there is a simple solution: use a member function.